# making matrix with eigenvalues

Tags: r

I am trying to make a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.
Here is my code:

```
E = eigen(cor(A))    
VAL = E$values    
VEC = E$vectors
```

so I get a vector with eigenvalues, but how do I turn it into a matrix.
I guess I can just use cbind() and manually input a e-value matrix, but there has to be a more correct way

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diag`:

```
diag(E$values)
```